# Get the time/date a record was created

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, is there an automatically instantiated field that has this information, or would I have to create a separate column in the model to keep track of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have columns called `created_at` and `updated_at`, they will update automatically. You can abbreviate that in your migration with `t.timestamps`, which now shows up by default (or did last time I created a model). If you're talking about an object stored in the database, there's no information about it other than what's in the table.

On a side note, if you're talking about an instance of an ActiveRecord it's best to say "record" instead of "object." The latter refers to any object that you instantiate, be it a record that you retrieve or just a simple `Foo.new`.

Comment: Actually they *are* objects. I wouldn't recommend calling them records. Those exit only in databases. Calling them ActiveRecord objects would be more accurate.

Comment: They are objects, and I said as much in my last sentence.  But when you say "get the time an object was created" the first thing I thought was "what time did the line Foo.new execute?"  The question isn't about when objects were created but about when records were created.  Each time you retrieve a record you create a new object and that's not what the question is asking about.  He's asking about when the record was created.

Comment: Changed the title of the question to more accurately reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: It sounded like you were recommending (in general) to call ActiveRecord instances "records"... I don't agree with that. That's all I am saying.

Comment: I apologize if I sounded that way - it was not my intention.  I was just trying to clarify what I was saying, which is about the distinction between the record and the object - namely that one record can be the record for many objects and that the question was about the record, not about an object created from the record.  I definitely agree with you that instances of ActiveRecord should be called "objects," not "records."  And thanks for the code markup edits in my response.

Answer (score 1):

Rails automatically stores when each record is created in `created_at` it also stores when the record was last updated in `updated_at`